# Generic type defaults to int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying the following example to learn the Generic typing in Python and can't figure out what is the default type for a Generic type.

An example from PEP 484 : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#scoping-rules-for-type-variables

```
from typing import (
    Generic,
    TypeVar
)

T = TypeVar('T')

class MyClass(Generic[T]):

    def meth_1(self, x: T) -> T: ...  # T here

    def meth_2(self, x: T) -> T: ...  # and here are always the same


a = MyClass()  # type: MyClass[int].  <------ why int here?
a.meth_1(1)    # OK
a.meth_2('a')  # This is an error!
```

I do not understand why `MyClass` defaults to `int` here? And `a.meth_2('a')` gives me a mypy error :

> Argument 1 to "meth_2" of "MyClass" has incompatible type "str";
> expected "int"  [arg-type

Anyone could shed some light on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`# type: MyClass[int]` gives the type checker a hint about the variable type of (saying `a` is a `MyClass[int]`). You can see this in PyCharm where it's highlighted green and thus leads to an error 2 lines later:

[image]

What that example is trying to illustrate is that once the type checker knows that `a` has type `MyClass[int]` it does **NOT** accept calls to `meth_1` or `meth_2` with a `str`.

This is in contrast with the example directly preceding it on the original page where it **IS** still possible (to call `meth_2` with a `str`).

Comment: Ah. So `# type: MyClass[int].` is a type annotation which will force `MyClass` has type of `int`.